# Call external declared variable inside the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a function to check if there is a data saved in "phonenumber" child  on my firebase database or not ..
the tests are OKEY! but inside this function I can't call an external declared variable !
this is code:

```
phoneNumberExistence: boolean;

FIREBASE_DATABASE.ref("Settings").child('phoneNumber').once('value', function(snapshot) {
      var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
      //console.log("Phone number existance: "+exists);
      if(exists){
        this.phoneNumberExistence = true; //the problem is here.. can't use this variable
        console.log("A phone number already exists.")
      }
      else{
        this.phoneNumberExistence = false; //the problem is here.. can't use this variable
        console.log("There is no phone number here :(");
      }
    })
```

Any idea ?
thanks

Comment: Personally, I ***never*** use `this` in Angular. Stick with `$scope`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow functions instead of `function(snapshot) {...}`

```
... .once('value', (snapshot) => {
  var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
  ...
});
```

Arrow Functions lexically bind their context so this actually refers to the originating context. For more details, you can read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4).

Comment: I didn't knew that type of functions, anyway your solution worked perfectly, thanks man

Comment: U r welcome. This an EcmaScript 6 feature, so you can also use it in TypeScript.